# Trigonometry - Solving and Equation with Cosec X

Tags: trigonometry

Verify, by calculation that the roots of the equation $\csc x = \frac{1}{2}x + 1$, where x is n radians, has roots in the interval $0<x<\frac{1}{2}\pi$ and that they lie between 0.5 and 1.

Comment: So, what's your doubt?

Comment: I tried solving this a lot but i got very confused about which root to take and i've tried and tried and tried but i just couldn't solve it... please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Please see here: [image]

The root $x=0.797$ lies in $(0,\frac {\pi}{2}) $ verifying the result. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The root may be found with Newton's method:

$$0=x+2-2\csc(x)$$

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n+2-2\csc(x_n)}{1+2\csc(x_n)\cot(x_n)}$$

With $x_0=0.8$, we get

$x_1=0.7967677637$

$x_2=0.7967790659$

$x_3=0.7967790660$

Which is the solution out ten places.

Comment: ???  Why the downvote?  Is it not a tad bit unreasonable?